# Adding Permissions Policy Header in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I am trying to add a [Permission Policy Header](https://www.w3.org/TR/permissions-policy-1/) to a Rails app (running Rails 6.1.4).

According to [this post](https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/10/01/rails-6-1-adds-http-feature-policy.html), Rails 6.1 should support this with the previous name of the feature (Feature Policy), but adding this code:

```rb
Rails.application.config.feature_policy do |f|
  f.camera       :none
  f.geolocation  :self, 'https://example.com'
  f.payment      :self, '*' 
end
```

fails with unknown method error:

```
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.6/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:97:in `method_missing': undefined method `feature_policy' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x000055dcdc6725c8 @root=#<Pathname:/vagrant/rails/myapp>
```

So my question is: Is this supported with a DSL initializer or not? And if not, is the below approach optimal for adding this custom header?

```rb
# application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_permissions_policy

  def set_permissions_policy
    response.headers["Permissions-Policy"] = [
      "geolocation=()",
      "camera=()",
      "fullscreen=()"
    ].join ', '
  end
end
```

EDIT:

I found out that [there is a method with a new name](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/ActionController/PermissionsPolicy.html) - `permissions_policy` - which works, but the header it generates is the using the old name `Feature-Policy` instead of the new name `Permissions-Policy` ([discussed in this Rails PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/41994)) - so my conclusion is still, to stick with the custom header instead of the DSL (unless more information becomes available).

Comment: Can you add the error you get ?

Comment: Added error message.